# JiBX Eclipse Plugin Error when compile

Tags: eclipse, jibx

I am trying to use JiBX with Ecplise Indigo and JiBX Plugin for Eclipse 1.2.3.
When the eclipse Plugin compiles the binding I get the following output and error:
OUTPUT:

```
JiBX build begin @ Mon May 14 08:22:56 CEST 2012
JiBX build Workspace invoked FULL build
JiBX bindAll begin
JiBX bindAll classpath: 
    .
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\charsets.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\localedata.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\jce.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\jsse.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\resources.jar
    C:\Programme\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
    ..eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\772\1\.cp\lib\bcel.jar
    ..eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\772\1\.cp\lib\jibx-bind-1.2.3.jar
    ..eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\772\1\.cp\lib\jibx-run-1.2.3.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\bin
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\bcel.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\jibx-bind.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\jibx-run.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\stax-api.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\wstx-asl.jar
    \JiBX-Mapping\lib\xpp3.jar
JiBX doMappings begin
JiBX doMappings using these mapping files: 
    \JiBX-Mapping\src\data.xml
    \JiBX-Mapping\src\binding.xml
JiBX parseMappedClasses begin
JiBX parseMappedClasses watching these mapped classes:
    \JiBX-Mapping\bin\Customer.class
JiBX parseMappedClasses end
JiBX doMappings end
Error running binding compiler
```

ERROR:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'JiBX Binding Builder' on project 'JiBX-Mapping'.
```

My Classpath is:
JiBX-Mapping/src/

My JiBX-Mapping-Path:
src/

The Code is from JiBX-Example here:
http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/tutorial/binding-start.html

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Best Regards 
Veote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say what is going wrong in your case, but you can get more information by switching on Verbose Compilation in the eclipse project properties

Answer (score 1):

veote,
What version of java are you using? There is an problem using jdk 1.7. If you are using jdk 1.7, just change your source compatibility to 1.6.
Don

Comment: I use JDK 1.6. I knew the problem with 1.7.